# How to hide all children nodes in Angular tree?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use [this tree](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkg8nh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.html)

Node model is:

```
interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  children?: FoodNode[];
  childVisible?: boolean;
}
```

I tried to hide all children nodes if parent has `childVisible` as false:

```
<ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
    <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet *ngIf="node.childVisible"></ng-container>
</ul>
```

But it does not work for me, how to hide them?

Also I have tried this:

```
 hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) =>
    node.childVisible && !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
```

Comment: what does your directive 'matTreeNodeOutlet' do?

Comment: It is from official documentation https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Comment: oh I see. sorry I had not seen the StackBlitz.
Anyway I'm not sure I get what the problem is. Your 'fruits' have "childVisible: false", and they are correctly hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, IMHO your example works fine. Unless I did not understand what you are trying to do.

In your code you have '`childVisible: false`' for Fruits, and they are hidden... now I modified it to display some more children of 'Green' but to hide the children of 'Orange'. It also works fine (don't forget that if you do not specify `childVisible` then it is `false` by default).
See my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkg8nh-mdykhl?file=src/app/tree-nested-overview-example.ts)